# Possible to view T-SQL syntax of a stored proc-based SqlCommand?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I was wondering if anybody knows of a way to retrieve the actual T-SQL that is to be executed by a SqlCommand object (with a CommandType of StoredProcedure) before it executes...

My scenario involves optionally saving DB operations to a file or MSMQ before the command is actually executed. My assumption is that if you create a SqlCommand like the following:

```
Using oCommand As New SqlCommand("sp_Foo")
    oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    oCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Param1", "value1"))
    oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

It winds up executing some T-SQL like:

```
EXEC sp_Foo @Param1 = 'value1'
```

Is that assumption correct? If so, is it possible to retrieve that actual T-SQL somehow? My goal here is to get the parsing, validation, etc. benefits of using the SqlCommand class since I'm going to be using it anyway. Is this possible? Am I going about this the wrong way? Thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to the log the SP call with its parameters in a friendly form?  Or you want to save this text to run it as a script later?

I think you're out of luck in the second case, because, I don't think SQLCommand calls SPs with SQL when you use it in CommandType.StoredProcedure mode.  If you look in the SQL Server profiler at the difference between CommandType.StoredProcedure with an SP "sp_whatever" and CommandType.Text with "EXEC sp_whatever", it's a different interface - the RPC interface.  I was always under the impression ADO.NET was never making a SQL string in the first case.  That's why you never have to worry about injection at that point, because parameters are always sent out of band - even if you have CommandType.Text with a parametrized query.

See this [blog post](http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2004/11/adonet-and-sql-server-optimization.html).

If you are trying to log operations, I guess you could pass your SQLCommand object to some generic object/method you write which extracts the command text and all the parameters and puts them in a nicely organized text form for logging.

Comment: Ah-ha. I'm in the latter case, and that's kind of what I was afraid of... It's not a huge deal to send the command object elsewhere and pull everything back out of it (or do it entirely differently.) I was just thinking that'd be a super-easy way to go about it. Anyway, thanks for the info... I should've read up more on CommandType.StoredProcedure.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

SQL Profiler might be of use here.  If you can execute the SP in SSMS with Profiler running, you can set it up to see the T-SQL commands being executed.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Profiler, connect to server, use the TSQL_SPs template (after you connect to the server, you get the "Trace Properties" box, fourth line down is your template selection).